# Getting error when connecting with external redshift database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Getting this error:

> PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to set parameter
>   "client_min_messages" to "warning" : SET client_min_messages TO
>   'warning'  when connecting with redshift database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N80fG.png)

My database.yml file setting looks like this

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: nacfhrcluster123.ctvpledrvuobs5.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com
  port: 5439
  username: nacfhr123
  password: NACFDChr12345!
  database: devnacfhrdc
  pool: 5
  schema_search_path: 'beta'
  timeout: 5000 
  min_messages: warning
```

Comment: Check your PG user's permissions.

Comment: you might want to edit your question to remove your password - unless it is a dummy one but it doesn't look like it

Comment: @JonScott I guess it's a little bit too late for this, so OP probably needs to change their password.

Comment: Yes agreed, you should expect that user/password to be widely available even after it is removed. hopefully it was just a dummy one.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your responses. I resolved the issue by adding a gem with the name 'activerecord5-redshift-adapter' in my gemfile. So you have to add below line in your gem file.

gem 'activerecord5-redshift-adapter'

And then run bundle install again.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realise that Redshift IS NOT Postgres. There are many differences.

One difference is that the available parameters are much different, the only parameters that can be set on Redshift are:

```
analyze_threshold_percent
datestyle
extra_float_digits
query_group
search_path
statement_timeout
wlm_query_slot_count
```

You will need to alter your rails connection so that is does not request this parameter to be set.

I guess that means removing `min_messages: warning`

Comment: Tried by removing min_messages parameter also but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. As far as I know there is no active records available for `Redshift` and it don't it make sense as well as `Redshift` is not a typical `RDBMS`.
We have similar scenario where we use ROR for front end for one of analytics and planing application.

Here is our app scenario:

Front-end : ROR
Database : mysql(OLTP)
Datawarehouse : Redshift(OLAP)

This is how data flows back and forth between ROR and Redshift.

- Insert/updates from ROR to Redshift(happens very rarely).
  For any operations from ROR that impacts something on data warehouse, ROR executes `PSQL` commands with specific query, not via active records.
- SELECT from Redshift(happens frequently)
  Similarly, for getting data from DW for various reason done via select query and redirection to file using `PSQL` command, then it import it into `OLTP` using `myssqlimport`.

Link for [psql](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html), [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) tools that we use.
Comment if you have further specific followup questions.